# Deleting items from datagrid (xml)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datagrid

I have a datagrid buttoncolumn which acts as delete buttons for my xml nodes.
The elements are simply displayed in a boundcolumn, so there names get displayed.

Each item generated gets a unique id (each time one is made id+++).
My question his how can i remove a item (the entire element node with that certain id) when i click on one of the buttons in the bound column?

```
<root>
   <element id="0">
      <name>One</name>
   </element>
   <element id="1">
       <name>Two</name>
   </element>
</root>

 protected void dg_DeleteCommand(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlFunctions.Remove(index);
    }/*dg_DeleteCommand*/
```

(function on other class, where all my xml methods are written)

```
public static void Remove(string index)
{
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLDoc.Load(XMLFile);
XPathNavigator nav = XMLDoc.CreateNavigator();

var node = nav.SelectSingleNode("/test/one[@id='" +???+ "']");
node.DeleteSelf();
XMLDoc.Save(XMLFile);
}
```

Edit: added datagrid

```
    <asp:View ID="viewDelete" runat="server">
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgDelete runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDeleteCommand="dg_DeleteCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="name" HeaderText="names" />
                <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ></asp:ButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>  
    </asp:View>
```

Comment: What is test in "/test/one..."?

Comment: oh sorry that should be /root/element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void dg_DeleteCommand(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)     
{
         XmlFunctions.Remove(grid selected value);     
}

public static void Remove(string itemValue) 
{
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");
   doc.Descendants("test")
         .Where(p=>p.Attribute("id") != null 
                   && p.Attribute("id").Value == itemValue)
         .SingleOrDefault().Remove();
}
```

Comment: What are the dataGridView1 exactly? Cannot seem to get the .SelectedCells or related index. Update my main post with the datagrid . Can only select selecteditem and selecteditemstyle. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load("yourxmlfile.xml");

XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(indice);
xmlnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlnode);

xmldoc.Save("yourxmlfile.xml");
```

I did this and it worked